# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Error (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, swift

When I run my application, it closes out because of this:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Also, the thread 1 error is coming from my AppDelegate.swift file on the line:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

I do not have any outlets in my Main.storyboard. Does anybody have any thoughts/tips as to why this NSException is being thrown?

Thanks!

Comment: Click the other threads in the list on the left, they may show you the exact line of code causing the issue.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on "all exceptions". (Click on "Breakpoints", click on "+", click on "Exception breakpoints".